# How to prevent "Firestore, Provided document path must not be null" error?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have an android app which have ~2k active users right now. It uses Firebase Firestore database for saving user data and other stuff. But recently I got this error and crash reports from my readUserDataFromDatabase function:

```
    private void readUserDataFromDatabase(String uid) {
    db.collection(Constants.PARAM_USERS)
            .document(uid) // (MainActivity.java:215)This is where the crash happens 
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    UserData userData = documentSnapshot.toObject(UserData.class);
                    if (userData == null) 
                        return;

                    tvName.setText(getString(R.string.welcome, userData.getName()));

                    Picasso
                            .get()
                            .load(userData.getPhotoUrl())
                            .placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.place_holder))
                            .transform(new RoundedCornersTransform())
                            .into(ivPhoto);

                    UserData.getInstance().setCredit(userData.getCredit());
                    UserData.getInstance().setPhotoUrl(userData.getPhotoUrl());
                    UserData.getInstance().setName(userData.getName());

                    if (userData.getInstanceId() != null) {
                        UserData.getInstance().setInstanceId(userData.getInstanceId());
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

This function runs after redirected from login activity with the successful login process:

```
private void setUser(final FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user == null)
        return;

    UserData.getInstance().setUserId(user.getUid());// I'm using this Uid for create node for user.
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection(Constants.PARAM_USERS).document(user.getUid());

    docRef
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    UserData userData = documentSnapshot.toObject(UserData.class);
                    if (userData == null) {
                        createUser(user);
                    } else {
                        redirectToHome(); //login succeed
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}
```

And calling readUserDataFromDatabase function like this from redirected activity:

```
 readUserDataFromDatabase(UserData.getInstance().getUserId());
```

Crash rate is around %1 but still I can't see what I'm missing here. Is there a chance that firebase user id returns null or after login succeed, readUserDataFromDatabase runs before

`UserData.getInstance().setUserId(user.getUid());`

function? I don't know. Thank you.

**Edit 1:** Added stack trace.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.alialacan.kpss/com.alialacan.kpss.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be
>   null.
>              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
>              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
>              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
>              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
>              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
>              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>              at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>
> ```
> Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
>        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:228)
>        at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(SourceFile:90)
>        at com.alialacan.kpss.MainActivity.readUserDataFromDatabase(MainActivity.java:215)
>        at com.alialacan.kpss.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114)
>        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7013)
>        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7004)
>        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
>        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
> ```

**Edit 2:** Here where is **setUser** function is calling:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Constants.RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.error_google_login,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hideProgress();
        }
    }
}

 private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d("", "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {                          
                        Log.d("", "signInWithCredential:success");
                        user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        setUser(user);
                    } else {
                        setUser(null);
                        Log.w("", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.error_email_already_exist,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        hideProgress();
                    }
                }
            });
}

 private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                        setUser(user);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.error_google_login,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        setUser(null);
                        hideProgress();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question with the details of the crash.  Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Hi, edited with stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages is saying that this code is passing a null value to readUserDataFromDatabase

```
readUserDataFromDatabase(UserData.getInstance().getUserId());
```

That means `UserData.getInstance().getUserId()` is returning null.

There's really not enough code here to fully diagnose the problem, since you're also not showing what calls `setUser`, but you need to track this back to the source.

Comment: Added functions calls setUser but setUser returning void when it's parameter is null anyway. Thank you for the answer. I will try to change the way that i cache user's data.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I just did not pass intent.putExtra to the next acticity, and in the next activity attempted to use it.

Answer (score 1):

For me clearing cache helped, as I just changed

`collection("Posts").orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)` to `collection("Posts").orderBy("like_count",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)`